Power Automate - Can't use Parse JSON Outputs
I'm trying to use Power Automate to obtain the employeeID field that is retrieved by Get user profile (V2) but not made available as a dynamic content.  This method is outlined in the answer to this question.
I've created a flow as shown here:

For the Parse JSON block I've tried using the outputs of a Compose block or the User from Graph API output from Get user profile (V2). The individual data items captured in the Parse JSON schema show up as dynamic content in subsequent blocks.
However, I can't seem to use actually use the outputs of Parse JSON.  When I run the flow, the test screen clearly shows that Parse JSON worked as I see the correct data in the "Outputs" screen:

However, when I add any of those outputs via Dynamic Content to a subsequent block, the data appears to be empty.  I've tried adding them to a Send an email (V2) block and to an Update Item block for a list (my original goal).  In neither case do I get any actual data that Parse JSON processed.
Am I missing a step, or misunderstanding how Parse JSON works?

Can you give us the JSON you’re parsing? Much easier to help if you provide that.

@Skin ehhm, it's right there in the screenshot

You can skip the Parse JSON step and go straight for the direct approach ...

The expression in Compose Employee ID is ...
body('Get_user_profile_(V2)')?['employeeId']


If it worked, feel free to flag it as the answer.  It rewards me and (may) help others.

Worked like a charm, even with a nested custom field our organization has.  My lesson learned, use "peek code" liberally.  That would have made the answer obvious.

try accessing the data with a formula instead of dynamic content.
body('YourParseJSONStepName')?['givenName']

This didn't work either.  No error given, but field remains blank.  The test indicates Parse JSON is creating output data, but it's almost as if it isn't there.  Fortunately, @skin 's answer on grabbing the data without Parse JSON step worked.

which is the exact same formula I used, only referencing a different step.

I know it is the same formula.  Clearly there is something funky about how I setup the Parse JSON block.
